# Optimal set based on bitwise operations

Tags: algorithm, set, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I vaguely remember seeing/hearing about an algorithm/technique/library for storing fixed sets of chars, where the set of characters gets compiled down to an O(1) series of bit operations. e.g. the code

```
isA(ch) := ch in {'a', 'A'}
```

gets compiled to

```
isA(ch) := ((ch as byte) && 0xdf) ^ 0x41) == 0
```

What is this called, and is there a good (embeddable) implementation of it somewhere?

Comment: What is it good for? You can always replace a **in** to a series of checks concatenated with **or**. In your case the only optimization is that it takes advantage that it reduces the set to one element by converting to uppercase first.

Comment: Was it with perfect hashing? That formula you have here looks more ad-hoc though, it's sort of accidentally possible

Comment: @MrSmith42 Sure, but this'd be more efficient. I assume that it'd degrade to "series of ORs" if there's no more efficient way.

Comment: @harold Possibly? That seems relevant, but gperf doesn't look like it does that. The point of this is to take advantage of the "accidental" patterns.

Comment: Are all sets of chars to be checked against known in advance?

Comment: I guess the [Karnaugh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) (for doing this by hand) or [McCluskey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) (for computers) algorithms would work just fine.

Comment: @Jojonete: Both (Karnaugh, McCluskey) only use `and`, `or` and `not` and do not take advantage of e.g. `xor` or other binary operations supported by the assembler.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I'm trying to use this to make a maximum-speed lexer.

Comment: @Jojonete: I think it might've been one of these, although I can't find a tool that does codegen with them after a couple Google searches... Ah well, if you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Unless you know of one that does, I'm starting to suspect that the one I was shown only did those operations; it was a long time ago, so my memory of it's a bit fuzzy.

Comment: @NathanRingo Thanks, but I don't really feel that just mentioning Karnaugh and McCluskey is such a worthy contribution to deserve the rep boost, and I also don't feel like actually implementing McCluskey.